# angular 2 load unload css , script files of component specific

Tags: angular

I am at the beginner stage in angular 2 .
In my angular 2 Single page application i have no. of script and css files to be load in one of my component.

Now when i open that component view in browser , it loads all files at head of html page and working well , But after that when i open other views, all css, js files are still present at there ,which is making slow down my application.

I need to unload these component specific files(js,css) when i switch to another views of application.

Is there any way or option in angular 2 , please suggest best one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lazy loading to load the feature modules as required.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load